# how can i post the value of this dynamic textbox to php script

Tags: php

i make a dynamic textbox through javascript now i want to post the data of all dynamically generated textboxes to php script and then insert into a table.
how can i do this...

```
<head>
<title>Dynamic Form</title>
<script language="javascript">
function changeIt()
{
var i = 1;
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext'+ i>"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" action="post" method="">
<input type="button" value="add another textbox" onClick="changeIt()">
<div id="my_div">
<input type="submit" value="save">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI, whenever you post your form at that time all the fields are posted on the php script, where you can get array of that textbox variable by using `for loop`.

```
ex: 
    $textboxarr = array();
    for($i = 0;$i<count($_POST['mytext']);$i++){
             $textboxarr = $_POST['mytext'][$i];
    }
```

now you having your all text boxes in the `$textboxarr`.try this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
<head>
<title>Dynamic Form</title>
<script language="javascript">
function changeIt()
{
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"&ltbr><input type='text' name='mytext[]'>"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" action="post" method="">
<input type="button" value="add another textbox" onClick="changeIt()">
<div id="my_div">
<input type="submit" value="save">
</body>
```

In php you will be able to use it as an array like

`$_POST['mytext'][0], $_POST['mytext'][1]` etc... or you can use a foreach loop for `$_POST['mytext']`